# Polymer v1.0 input validation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Noob at polymer here, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to learn how to create a form, one that requires the user to input text into a textbox, before hitting "Submit". Should the user hit "Submit" without anything in the textbox, the textbox is highlighted red, and displays an error message, etc.

Here's my code (no validation yet) so far:

```
<dom-module id="accountability-ticket">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog with-backdrop entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" id="diagTicket">
            <h2>I Own It Ticket</h2>
            <div>
                <paper-input-container id="gcashDeco" required error="GCash Ref. Required">
                    <input id="gcashText" is="iron-input">
                </paper-input-container>
                <div class="ctrlButtons flex">  
                    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
                    <paper-button on-click="confirmClick">Submit</paper-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "accountability-ticket",
    confirmClick: function(event){
        console.log(event);
        var gCashDeco = document.getElementById('gcashDeco');
        var gCashText = document.getElementById('gcashText');   
    }
});

</script>
```

I've been reading the Polymer documentation, and so far came up with two things:

1. `<paper-input>` doesn't validate, per se, according to v0.5 - It must be wrapped in `<paper-input-decorator>` first.
2. Version 1.0 is even less clear than that, with `<paper-input-container>` instead of `<paper-input-decorator>`, and mixed tags in the demo pages.

Given that I want to stick with the latest version (v1.0), what do I need to add to my code to get it to check if the textbox is empty, and display an error message if it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the Polymer docu is somewhat confusing, but as a general rule of thumb: always have a look at the behaviours the element is equiped with.

So, `paper-input` (in 1.0) comes with [`PaperInputBehavior`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=Polymer.PaperInputBehavior) and this implies that you can simply write the following:

```html
<paper-input label="Input label" required error-message="Field required!"></paper-input>

<paper-input label="Input label" minlength="4" maxlength="10" auto-validate></paper-input>

<paper-input label="Input label" pattern="MY_REGEX" auto-validate></paper-input>

<paper-input label="Input label" validator="myvalidator"></paper-input>
```

`auto-validate` makes the input – of course – validate as it is being typed into. `myvalidator` must be an element implementing the [`IronValidatorBehavior`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-validator-behavior?active=Polymer.IronValidatorBehavior) and inserted somewhere on the page. If you don't want the fields to be auto-validating or wanna do it yourself, call `validate()` on that field or set the `invalid`-flag and the error message will be shown. You can even adjust the message programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Are there examples on how to call the `validate()` using javascript you could point me to?

Comment: Within a Polymer object: `this.$.myInputId.validate()`

Answer (score 2):

While the `validator` seems to be useful, I've found it to be simple enough to test the inputs directly. This will do what you need:

```
...
<div>
    <paper-input-container id="gcashDeco">
    <paper-input-error>Field is empty</paper-input-error>
    <input id="gcashText" is="iron-input" value="{{gcashInput::input}}">
    </paper-input-container>

    <div class="ctrlButtons flex">  
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-tap="confirmClick">Submit</paper-button>
    </div>
</div>
...

...
Polymer({
is: "accountability-ticket",

confirmClick: function() {
    if (this.gcashInput == null)
    {
        //show error
        this.$.gcashDeco.invalid = true;
    }
}
```

This `paper-input-error` element is referenced by the id of whatever `paper-input-container` it is inside of. Setting it's `invalid` property to `true` shows the error, and `false` hides it.

```
<paper-input-error>Field is empty</paper-input-error>
```

This next snippet binds the field's input value to a variable `this.gcashInput` which you can access inside `confirmClick` or any other method.

```
{{gcashInput::input}}
```

As a final note, getting id's of elements inside of your Polymer element is done like this:

```
this.$.gcashDeco
```

Not the way you would with vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('gcashDeco');
```

The latter, vanilla JS way, would search the main DOM, not the Shadow DOM where your element resides. So, use `document.getElementById()` if you need to search the DOM, and use `this.$.elemendId` if you need to search your element for an id.

Comment: hahaha, i like the idea of using `this.$.gcashDeco.invalid = true;`. Thanks for the trick

Comment: One other approach is to use a CSS marker class on all input fields, then select those fields, and call validate on each one. For example, you might have <paper-input class="validatable" ...